# An example of Noether normalization

Tags: commutative-algebra

> Let $A=k[x_1,x_2]/(x_2^2-x_1^3+x_1)$. As an example of Noether normalization, determine elements $y_1,\ldots,y_m\in A$, algebraically independent over $k$, such that $A$ is a finite $k[y_1,\ldots,y_m]$-algebra.

This is a problem in the Klaus Hulek's *Elementary Algebraic Geometry*. I think the book's proof of Noether normalization is not actually constructive...

Could anyone show me how to determine the $y_1,\ldots,y_m$ ?

Comment: Well, it doesn't say "application", it says "example.  Have you tried some things?  Have you looked at simpler examples?  Here's the question that should always be asked first: What is the simplest finitely generated $k$-algebra for which you cannot calculate a noether normalization?

Comment: Oh, and one more question, perhaps an important one: How large do you think $m$ is, in this example?

Comment: I didn't encounter any example of this kind before...so I have got no clue to how I may find such y1~ym. Certainly, m must be lower than 3. Could you give any hint?

Comment: If you know this basic theorem relating the dimension to transcendence degree, you can determine $m$ immediately, assuming that you know the Krull dimension of $A$.

Comment: Honestly, almost anything you try will lead to progress here.  Like I said if the problem is too hard, try to do it for something with one variable.

Comment: The proof of Noether normalization which can be found in almost every book on commutative algebra is constructive. It can be used to find specific elements as required.

Answer (score 1):

The Krull dimension of $A$ is $1$, so almost every choice of $y\in A-k$ is good.